# They saw my touching the chair?

Tags: grammar

a) They heard **my arriving** (my playing/my singing). – Gerund

b) They saw **my touching** of the chair.              - Gerund  - wrong

They saw **me touching** the chair.

Could you, please, explain why the second sentence is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I'm curious why (a) ("They heard my arriving") is listed as correct...? Normally you would not use a gerund as a noun if there's already an existing noun that describes that action. "Playing" and "singing" are used as nouns because there is no other way to concisely say "the way someone plays an instrument or sings". But "arriving" does already have a noun--"arrival". "They heard my arrival." If they don't want to use the noun for some reason, then "they heard me arriving" would be preferable and less awkward for the same reasons that "They saw me touching the chair" is preferable.

Comment: filistinist, thank you for your correction!